# Copy/paste within VSCode does not preserve leading spaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, copy-paste

[image: Recreating the issue]

When copying block of text from within VSCode and pasting in the same document (or other VSCode documents), leading spaces are stripped. When writing in YAML or other space delineated formats, this essentially breaks copy/paste functionality.

Auto-indent is set to "FULL" as default, changing to any of the other options does not seem to affect this.

Enabling or disabling "format on paste" does not seem to affect this either.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. For me, setting `editor.autoIndent` to anything other than `"full"` causes the leading spaces of the copied text to be kept after pasting. You'll need to provide more details so I can reproduce your issue (a [mre]). I was trying with JSON. Maybe if you provide some minimal example YAML with exact steps on what to copy and where to paste, I can reproduce it.

Comment: Starting VSCode with all extensions disabled resolves this issues. Copy/paste works as expected within VSCode, I will update if I can narrow down the specific extension causing this issue.

Comment: do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it. In your question post, please also add the output of `code --list-extensions`